# Triggering commands by their command ID or a custom string alias

Tags: visual-studio-code, alias

I'd like to trigger a command listed in the `Default Keybindings` view from the **Command Palette**.

For example, I'd like to be able to trigger one of commands listed below, **by name** (or a string alias of my choice), from the **Command Palette** (`Command + Shift + P`).

How do I do that?

```
// ---- From "Default Keybindings" -----
//
...
// - workbench.extensions.action.showExtensionsWithIds
// - workbench.extensions.action.showInstalledExtensions
// - workbench.extensions.action.showLanguageExtensions
// - workbench.extensions.action.showPopularExtensions
// - workbench.extensions.action.showRecommendedExtensions
// - workbench.extensions.action.stopExtensionHostProfile
// - workbench.extensions.action.updateAllExtensions
// - workbench.extensions.installMissingDepenencies
// - workbench.files.action.acceptLocalChanges
// - workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders
// - workbench.files.action.compareFileWith
// - workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer
// - workbench.files.action.refreshFilesExplorer
// - workbench.files.action.revertLocalChanges
// - workbench.files.action.saveAllInGroup
// - workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer
// - workbench.output.action.clearOutput
// - workbench.userData.actions.continueSync
// - workbench.userData.actions.login
// - workbench.userData.actions.logout
// - workbench.userData.actions.stopSync
// - workbench.userData.actions.syncStart
// - workbench.view.extension.atlascode-drawer
// - workbench.view.extension.databaseExplorer
// - workbench.view.extension.gitlens
// - workbench.view.extension.references-view
// - workbench.view.extension.test
// - workbench.view.remote
// - workbench.view.search.focus
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Default Keybindings` listing does not show the title of each command as it appears in the Command Palette.  You would typically use that title/alias to search in the Command Palette.  Using the plain command, like `workbench.extensions.action.showLanguageExtensions` is a pain because you need to type the whole command out exactly right for it to be found in the Command Palette.

You could also put the command into the `KeyBoard Shortcuts` search to learn its built-in alias.

---

There is no way at present - but it is on the backlog - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50836 - to be able to make your own aliases for commands.

However, I wrote an extension to do this that is in preview, [command alias](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.command-alias) that allows you to create your own aliases for commands.  For example:

```json
  "command aliases": {
    "explorer.newFile": "touch",
    "explorer.newFolder": "mkdir"
  },
```

would give you a `touch` and a `mkdir` listing/alias right in the Command Palette that would trigger `explorer.newFile` and `explorer.newFolder` respectively.

[image: demo of command alias extension]